# Cumulative count of days using indicator column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to generate a new variable "Counter" in Python that counts the number of days since the latest value of 1 in the column "Dummy".
The data is sorted upon dates and then on IDs.
If the ID has not previously have had a value of 1 in "Dummy", the counter should yield the value -1.

The original data looks like the first 3 columns below. The fourth column "Counter" is the desired result/variable, which should be added to the panda dataframe:

```
Date        ID Dummy Counter

2017-10-01   1   0   -1

2017-12-31   1   1   -1

2017-12-31   2   1   -1

2018-01-15   2   0   15

2018-01-25   1   0   25

2018-02-01   1   1   32

2018-02-02   1   0    1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is counter in row 1 `-1`,  and for row 3 wheree ID 2 has not been seen yet, it is 15?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - You're completely right! I've now edited the question (hopefully, it's formulated right now).

Comment: I don't think there's a vectorised solution, you'll need a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a vectorised solution using groupby + apply:

Broke it into 2 lines to make it more understandable, but it's still a bit convoluted:

Read Your Data:

```
s = '''Date        ID Dummy
2017-10-01   1   0
2017-12-31   1   1
2017-12-31   2   1
2018-01-15   2   0
2018-01-25   1   0
2018-02-01   1   1
2018-02-02   1   0'''

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s+', index_col=None)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Proposed Solution:

```
last_valid = lambda gdf: (gdf['Date'] - gdf['Date'].where(gdf['Dummy']==1, np.nan).ffill().shift(1))
df['Counter'] = df.groupby('ID').apply(last_valid).reset_index('ID', drop=True).dt.days.fillna(-1)
```

Output:

```
    Date    ID  Dummy   Counter
0   2017-10-01  1   0   -1.0
1   2017-12-31  1   1   -1.0
2   2017-12-31  2   1   -1.0
3   2018-01-15  2   0   15.0
4   2018-01-25  1   0   25.0
5   2018-02-01  1   1   32.0
6   2018-02-02  1   0   1.0
```